# Siteminder Authentication and Android

Tags: android, cookies, siteminder

I'm attempting to connect to a resource that's protected by SiteMinder.  Eventually, the app will be in PhoneGap, but for now, I'm just testing the basic communication.  When I request the resource, SiteMinder intercepts the request and presents a login screen.  After posting the username and password, I can see in a WireShark trace that siteminder does issue a set-cookie header with an SMSession value, but the next request from Android Emulator does not include the cookie.

The same code / environment works fine from a desktop browser.  Is there a limit on the cookie size or format that is accepted by Android?

Answer (score 0):

are you testing this from the android browser? there shouldn't be any limitations to the cookies that the android browser will accept. Have you tried going into the browser settings and ensuring that all the right settings to accept cookies are enabled?

Comment: I found through testing that the error I was experiencing was a combination of server misconfiguration (http vs. https) and a change in phonegap to start whitelisting URLs in 1.1.  I had to whitelist the domain in the phonegap.xml file to ensure that it remained in the web view.  Additionally, the siteminder server was requiring SSL connections to create the secure cookie.  Once we changed our url scheme to https and whitelisted the domain things started working fine.  We now have siteminder authentication working with Android and iOS devices.